# How to mock a private static final inner class instance?

Tags: java

How to mock private static final nested class instance?

```
Mockito.when(mock).thenReturn(requiredData);
```

mock contains creation of new Instance of private static final nested class.

Comment: please read this how to ask question section http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PowerMock https://code.google.com/p/powermock/. This works with Mockito and allow you to mock things you can't usually mock like private static methods.